# Force PC to Output 4k 60hz

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, streaming, tv, 4k-resolution

Ok so I have a bit of a strange setup that I'm trying to get working.

I bought a brand new LG C8 OLED 4K TV and put it in my livingroom. I own a new gaming PC that's in my office (on a different floor and far from TV) which is hooked up to a 2k monitor. I would like to stream my desktop to my TV and play 4k 60fps games.

I've been doing this for about a year with my old 1080p TV. I was using [Nvidia Moonlight](https://moonlight-stream.org/) to stream from my PC to a laptop that was next to the TV and connected through HDMI. This worked flawlessly, and also supports 4k streams.

***Issue 1:***

I was able to get my laptop to display 4k by displaying only on the TV, and setting the resolution to 4k.

However on my gaming PC Windows 10 will only let me increase my resolution to 2k, because that's what the connected monitor supports. And I can't extend the display or anything because there's technically just the one display connected.

Is there a way I can force my PC to stream 4k content without having a 4k displaying physically connected?

***Issue 2:***

When I set my laptop to 4k, the highest refresh rate that it would allow was 30hz. I'm using HDMI 2.0 so I'm not sure why this is happening. As far as I understand, if I get my PC streaming in 4k but leave my laptop in 1080p, it will downsample the 4k to 1080p on my TV, correct? I haven't been able to test this yet because I need issue 1 resolved first, but it's a big concern of mine. Anyone know if this will be an issue or if there's a work around?

**EDIT:**
The laptop connected to the TV has an 850m in it, which is not strong enough to run 4k games at 60fps. This is why I'm only using it as an intermediary device.

My gaming PC has a ROG Strix 1070ti. This is the computer in my office and the one I want to stream from.

Comment: You can upscale, but it is nowhere near the _true_ quality of 4K. This is only achievable with a 4K screen...

Comment: Depending on the graphics card in your PC you may be limited to HDMI 1.4 which only supports 4k @ 30Hz. A newer graphics card may be needed.

Comment: Are you sure your hardware is able to support 4k resolutions?  It sounds like your laptop is indeed capable of supporting 4k.  "I would like to stream my desktop to my TV and play 4k 60fps games." - Using what hardware exactly?

Comment: Until we know what hardware is in your computer we cannot tell you why it is not supporting the modes you are after. We have many questions and answers regarding this and they all boil down to needing hardware that supports HDMI 2.0 or better: https://superuser.com/search?q=4k+60hz

Comment: I've added an edit to my question. Mokubai you might be right about my laptop being limited to HDMI 1.4, I'll look into it more. Will that be a bottleneck if I get 4k streaming on my PC working?